# How to ignore resize event in Qt3?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt3

when i increase left dock area size (manually) main window increases its size also. but it has no limit!. it can get wider than screen size. i want to prevent it. i tried re-implementing  main window's resizeEvent() method. this is what i have tried.

```
void MyMain::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e)
{
     if (newMainWindowWidth > screenWidth)
     {
          leftDockWindow->setFixedExtentWidth(
                   leftDockWidth - (newWidth - screenWidth));
          leftDockWindow->adjustSize();
          adjustSize(); // flicker effect :(
     }
}
```

this works. but it has a flicker effect because i'm adjusting size again. i think that i can solve this by ignoring the event. but i can't find a way to do that. please help !! thanks.

Comment: Why you don't use minimum size and fixed size policy instead?

Comment: I can't use fixed size because i should allow resizing. Application will run on multiple monitors...

Comment: Ok.. it can be done by re-implementing MainWindow's eventFilter() method. thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is ...

```
bool MyClass::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() == QEvent::Resize)
    {
        if (obj == myObj)
        {
            doSomethingWithObj(); 
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, e);;
    }
}
```